# Fetch 'Liked By this page' - list using restfb API

Tags: api, restfb

Hello: I am new to restfb api. I want to fetch list of all pages that have been liked by a page. Example: Coca-Cola page has likes 'Coca-Cola Freestyle', 'The Coca-Cola Company', 'Live Music Festival' and other 11 pages.

Which class.method shall I use? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure facebook wont let you directly fetch all the pages liked by another page. You would require proper (Page) access token for that.